# How can schemas be applied to website design?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, vision

If a "schema is a cognitive framework or concept that helps organize and interpret information. Schemas can be useful because they allow us to take shortcuts in interpreting the vast amount of information that is available in our environment." then how can we best apply this to user experience design for websites?

Specifically I'm after the answer to the following question, but that's not to say that my question about how schemes can be applied to website design in general is still not pertinent.

Which of the following statements regarding schema is true?

1. When two neurons have activated the connections between them are momentarily interrupted
2. Approximately 10 million neurons in the human brain are used to store information
3. Some nodes and links are so strong that they can be retrieved as a unit
4. Memories that are reconstructed incorrectly are called schema

Comment: Hmm, the titular question is quite interesting, but the side questions (a-d) all seem very problematic. I don't mean to be overly harsh, but my answer to all of them would be: None of them are true, and I'm not sure what led you to think that they could be. You should unpack your current beliefs on what schema are, since it appears you might be working from some faulty premises.